# Access to the path 'C:\actions-runner\_work_PipelineMapping\account-name\github-actions-demo-app\PipelineFolder.json' is denied

Tags: github, build, action, github-actions

I am using GitHub Actions with a self-hosted runner but now I am experiencing a failure in the build process just at the beginning. It says this :

**Access to the path 'C:\actions-runner_work_PipelineMapping\account-name\github-actions-demo-app\PipelineFolder.json' is denied.**

Since this morning everything was good. There was no build problem. What and where is the problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.